# How cassandra replicates data in virtual nodes?

Tags: cassandra

How cassandra replicates data in virtual nodes?

(1) cassandra replicates data randomly in virtual nodes.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeVnodesUsing_c.html#concept_ds_lmw_gnf_fk

"Ring with virtual nodes" image shows like as if cassandra replicates data randomly in virtual nodes.

or

(2) according to the replication strategy

[How cassandra replicates data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855080/how-cassandra-replicates-data)

If you use virtual nodes, the same idea is used but virtual nodes will be skipped as replicas if the physical node has already received the key.