# Cassandra Data distribution and Replication Concept

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I have one query regarding it with respect to Data distribution and replication. Cassandra uses a concept of Consistent Hashing to determine data portion for each node. At the same in Cassandra data is replicated to each node in subsequent writes to ensure consistency in case of any node failover. So does it means that each node has same set of data so that data can fetched from any node. If there is concept of Consistent hashing then how this is ensured.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How cassandra replicates data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855080/how-cassandra-replicates-data)

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855080/how-cassandra-replicates-data
and the documentation here http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html